# Run "mvn test" failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components)

Tags: maven, soapui, pom.xml

I try to run command like "**mvn -B -f ./pom.xml test**" but got error message like below:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.676 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-01T20:27:24+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.1.2:test (default) on project apitest-hfa: Execution default of goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.1.2:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.1.2': java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR] roleHint: com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.1.2:test
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

**But this command can work well on my another machine, and it also all pass when I try it with SoapUIPro software but not command**, I can't figure out what's wrong with my pom.xml, is there anything I have missed in my pom dependencies?

Really need some help, thanks a lot.

Screenshots like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhj1K.png)

Comment: Probably related to your environment if it works on your other machine. If you're familiar with docker, could you try to execute your command inside a container (just to be sure it works on a clean environment like a container), or inside a clean VM. Anyway, could you reproduce the problem with a smaller example, and share the `pom.xml` as text (not image)?

Comment: Are you using licensed one ???

Comment: You will need to post the rest of your soapui-pro-maven-plugin configuration. From the information provided, it is just a lot of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following which are missing from your dependency list -

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`org.codehaus.plexus` can be solved the issue.

If Possible, can you share your `pom` file, that would be easier to identify!!!

Comment: Looks it's JDK version related, see here: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Run-quot-mvn-test-quot-failed-Unable-to-load-the-mojo-test-or/m-p/185476#M42487